# Trying to build a search engine for my website

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to find the best way to create a search engine for my website.  All of the items that need to be searched are in the mysqli database, but I also have tables in the database that need to be excluded from the search (ie. Users information, navigation menu tables, etc).  The only solution that I have come up with so far is to search each table individually for that key word and then display the results.
Is there an easier way to do this?  I would like to have a ‘table group’ or something like that so my query could be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_group WHERE any_column LIKE “%search_string%”
```

The database has around 30 tables right now, but tables can be dynamically added and this will grow as the site is used more.  What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: I suggest you to use Sphinx http://sphinxsearch.com/ or Elasticsearch http://www.elasticsearch.org/ for full text search. Make a research on those technologies

Comment: you can use [Google Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/coop/cse/) in your website.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pursuit the idea of creating a search engine querying to the database, I think you have to query for the metadata of the database: the list of tables and the list of fields each table has.

However, this is difficult to follow because at the end you have to present the information to the user in a printable view: it isn't the same finding a proper name (and hence you have to present the page userInfo.php -to say an example- to the user) or a name of the company (and therefore you have to present a totally different page.

I think at least you have to create search elements based on the pages you have in the application. This means that you have to create a table with the information for the search engine: how to present this information, in what tables/fields should it search, etc.

Even if there will be tricks. What if the user searchs for "smyth"?? Have the search engine be smart enough to return "smith"?? And if you have two fields, one with the name and other wit the surname, what will happen the user types "john smith"??